# Angular how to deal with unavailable URLs requested by $http.get or $http.jsonp, which are executed by $q.all()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I've the following code:

```
eventResourcesCall = $http.jsonp('https://apicall/to/serverA');
eventsDetailsCall = $http.get('https://apicall/to/serverB');

$q.all([eventResourcesCall, eventsDetailsCall]).then(function(values){
    //process data manipulation and merging
});
```

The problem is that serverA and ServerB might not be available sometimes, and when one of those are unavailable, the data processing code stops and I get an error similar to the one described below:

```
GET https://apicall/to/serverA?jsonp=angular.callbacks._0 404 (Not Found)
```

Can any one point me to a documentation or describe on the answer how to properly deal with unavailable URL requested by $http and executed by $q.all()?

What I would like to be able to do is to get an indication that the URL is not accessible and then avoid the data processing code abortion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would use indirect promises:

```
var d1 = $q.defer(), d2 = $q.defer();

function NetworkError(reason) { this.reason = reason; }

eventResourcesCall = $http.jsonp('https://apicall/to/serverA').then(
    function(response) {
        d1.resolve(response);
    },
    function(err) {
        d1.resolve(new NetworkError(err));
    }
);
eventsDetailsCall = $http.get('https://apicall/to/serverB').then(
    function(response) {
        d2.resolve(response);
    },
    function(err) {
        d2.resolve(new NetworkError(err));
    }
);

$q.all([d1, d2]).then(function(values){
    var eventResources = values[0], eventsDetails = values[1];

    if( eventResources instanceof NetworkError ) {
        // handle error
    }
    else {
        // eventResources is good, use it
    }

    // and so on...
});
```

So the indirect promises are allways resolved and the `all()` succeeds. But the resolution value may be of the special `NetworkError` class which signals the actual error in this request.

---

This is definitely bulky, but could be improved with some utility methods, e.g.:

```
function makeIndirectPromise(httpPromise) {
    var ret = $q.defer();
    httpPromise.then(
        function(response) {
            ret.resolve(response);
        },
        function(err) {
            ret.resolve(new NetworkError(err));
        }
    );
    return ret.promise;
}
```

And the code above changes to:

```
function NetworkError(reason) { this.reason = reason; }

function makeIndirectPromise(httpPromise) { /* see above */ }

eventResourcesCall = makeIndirectPromise($http.jsonp('https://apicall/to/serverA'));
eventsDetailsCall = makeIndirectPromise($http.get('https://apicall/to/serverB'));

$q.all([eventResourcesCall, eventsDetailsCall]).then(function(values){
    var eventResources = values[0], eventsDetails = values[1];

    if( eventResources instanceof NetworkError ) {
        // handle error
    }
    else {
        // eventResources is good, use it
    }

    // and so on...
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution - it keeps your data from the successful calls, and gives you the opportunity to handle each error individually. This is opposed to the sweeping $q.all error handler, which, I believe, will not pass along values from the successful promises.

Comment: Nice explanation of everything...fav'd this question for later! +1

Comment: Nikos, On your code neither eventResources nor eventsDetails evaluates to an instance of NetworkError if the url is not reachable.

The values returned by $q.all() contain just the following 3 items:

An object named "promise", a function named "reject" and a function named "resolve".

eventResourcesCall and eventsDetailsCall only return something useful after the $q.all().then() code has already run.

Any comments?

(note: I pressed enter by accident before finish typing this comment)

Comment: Yes, of course. It was a typo in `makeIndirectPromise()`, you need to return `ret.promise`. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

From Angular doc to [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q): as $http returns a promise, you can catch promise rejection using either:

```
$q.all([eventResourcesCall, eventsDetailsCall]).then(function(values){
    //process data manipulation and merging on Success
}).catch(function(errors){
    //Deal with your $http errors
}).finally(function(data){

});
```

or

```
$q.all([eventResourcesCall, eventsDetailsCall]).then(function(values){
    //process data manipulation and merging on Success
}, function(errors){
    //Deal with your $http errors
});
```